# How to check two arrays of object has the same property value or not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

i have two arrays and want to check if all IDs is the same or not

```
let a = [
          {id:0, name:"test0"},
          {id:1, name:"test1"}
         ];

let b = [
          {id:0, name:"test0"},
          {id:1, name:"test1"}
         ];
```

the above arrays we see it's equal

and the way I tired like this

```
JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b) => True
```

I read the `JSON.stringify` it's affected the Performance if we have big arrays

so is there another way to get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const areEqual = (a = [], b = []) => {
  // compare length of arrays
  if(a.length !== b.length) {
    return false;
  }
  // get sorted lists of ids
  const arr1 = a.map(({id}) => id).sort(), arr2 = b.map(({id}) => id).sort();
  // iterate over the arrays and compare, if at an index, items mismatch, return false
  for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  // if it passes all the items, return true
  return true;
}

console.log( 
  areEqual(
    [{id:0, name:"test0"}, {id:1, name:"test1"}], 
    [{id:0, name:"test0"}, {id:1, name:"test1"}]
  )
);
```

Another solution using `Set`:

```js
const areEqual = (a = [], b = []) => {
  // compare length of arrays
  if(a.length !== b.length) {
    return false;
  }
  // get ids set in b
  const idsSetInB = new Set(b.map(({id}) => id));
  // iterate over a, and check if the id of an item is not in b
  for(let {id} of a) {
    if(!idsSetInB.has(id)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  // if it passes all the items, return true
  return true;
}

console.log( 
  areEqual(
    [{id:0, name:"test0"}, {id:1, name:"test1"}], 
    [{id:1, name:"test1"}, {id:0, name:"test0"}]
  )
);
```

Comment: Nice code.  I'll point out that any solution will be O(N) for performance.  Longer arrays will require more work to process regardless.

Comment: Thanks, What the issues with the first answer before the Edit?
 `_getIds(a).sort().join(',')`

Comment: @OliverD it works, but I edited the solution in case you want to check for types as well.

Comment: Question, are ids unique in each array?

Comment: @MajedBadawi yes it's unique!

Comment: I added another approach which should handle big arrays better. @duffymo thanks for the comment, feel free to suggest changes/other approaches.

Comment: @MajedBadawi Thanks, i learn new things today^^

Comment: Hey @MajedBadawi can you please check the Edit section, thanks?

Comment: @MajedBadawi can you please check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67849438/cant-synchronise-the-updated-array-in-zustand][Q] I Separated it "if u have checked the Edit Section"